# Retrieving a Journey Builder Interaction ID using Data Binding

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, databinding

I'm trying to find out whether it's possible to retrieve the Interaction ID (for a running Interaction) using Data Binding. The Interaction ID is different from `{{Context.PublicationId}}` and `{{Context.DefinitionId}}` (in the Interaction context).

I'm referring to the ID that is indicated in the Interaction Plan Canvas URL. The identifier appears between the `%23` string (a URL encoded # character) and before the `/` character. For example, an Interaction identifier is highlighted below.

[image: Retrieiving Interaction Key]

Is it possible to retrieve this value using Data Binding?

I'd like to use this as part of an `inArgument` for a Custom Activity. For example, in the [custom-activity-deskapi-node](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node) sample application, the Interaction ID is "hard coded" in the update-case config.json file:

```
"arguments": {
    "execute": {        
        "inArguments":[ 
            { "caseID":"{{Interaction.0d59b900-04bd-443b-9c21-e0c09e76e9dc.caseID}}" }
        ],          
        "outArguments": [               
        ],
        "url": "https://mydomain.herokuapp.com/ixn/activities/update-case/execute/",
        "verb": "POST",
        "body": "",
        "header": "",
        "format": "json",
        "useJwt": false,
        "timeout": 10000
    }
},
```

While this works and is fine for demonstrative purposes, it means that this Custom Activity can only be used in a defined Interaction. Ideally, I'd like to retrieve this value at runtime and change my `inArgument` so it can be used by any Interaction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Realizing this question is over a year old I thought I would still add my answer that does not require an API call but instead uses Postmonger.

Using the Postmonger events `requestInteraction` and `requestedInteraction` you can get the JSON of the entire interaction, including the InteractionID and any activity keys.  You can then parse the JSON and set that value as an inArgument.

[Postmonger Interaction Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/using-postmonger.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the 'activity customer key' there. It will look like "REST-1", "WAIT-3", "MOBILE-2", etc.

```
{ "caseID":"{{Interaction.REST-1.caseID}}" }
```

You can get it by querying for details about your interaction:

```
headers: 
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json
GET https://jbinteractions.exacttargetapps.com/fuelapi/interaction/v1/interactions/<guid>?extras=all&versionNumber=9
```

Have you tried any of the Context values?

From the [doc](http://code.exacttarget.com/app-development/journey-builder-development/interactions/how-data-binding-works.html):

- Context.PublicationId - The publication ID may be important for the currently executing activity if it needs to be associated to a particular publication (version) of the interaction.
- **Context.DefinitionId** - The definition ID is an identifier that can be used to specify the interaction. It could have similar uses as PublicationId.
- Context.DefinitionInstanceId - This is the identifier for the actual instance of an interaction, meaning, each Contact ran through the engine would have a different identifier. This would be useful for matching logs.

Also, JB posts a payload to your activities' execute method with some values may be useful at runtime:

```
      "body": {
        "inArguments": [
          ...
        ],
        "outArguments": [
          ...
        ],
        "activityObjectID": "<guid>",
        "journeyId": "<guid>",
        "activityId": "<guid>",
        "definitionInstanceId": "<guid>",
        "activityInstanceId": "<guid>",
        "keyValue": "jdoe@bh.exacttarget.com",
        "mode": 0
      },
```